# WndProc missing WM_KEYUP event on Windows 7

Tags: .net, winforms

I just wrote a textbox class to capture WM_KEYDOWN/WM_KEYUP/WM_SYSKEYDOWN/WM_SYSKEYUP events:

```
Public Class MyTextbox
    Inherits TextBox

    Public Const WM_KEYDOWN = &H100
    Public Const WM_KEYUP = &H101
    Public Const WM_SYSKEYDOWN = &H104
    Public Const WM_SYSKEYUP = &H105

    Protected Overrides Sub WndProc(ByRef m As Message)

            Select Case m.Msg
                Case WM_KEYDOWN, WM_KEYUP, WM_SYSKEYDOWN, WM_SYSKEYUP

                    Dim vk = m.WParam
                    Form1.ListBox1.Items.Add(m.Msg.ToString & " - " & vk.ToInt64)
            End Select

            MyBase.WndProc(m)


    End Sub


End Class
```

It works well on Windows 10 , When I press the Ctrl + Shift key, I received 4 lines (up & down key for ctrl + shift) on the listbox

However on Windows 7, when I press Ctrl+ Shift key, It's missing on KEYUP event.

Comment: Have you checked if you see them with Spy++ (from SDK) : [Spy++ TextBox](https://i.ibb.co/25VgCgj/Spy-Text-Box.jpg)

Comment: What is the `#End If` you have there? What's the condition? Do you have some other code that handles key presses there? With this code alone, you should receive overlapping messages when you press `CTRL+SHIFT`. Both on KeyUp and KeyDown.

Comment: @Jimi  Sorry it's my mistake when copy and paste to stackoverflow, i just remove the #End if line. It's seems a bug on WIndows 7, I receive only 3 events fired

Comment: I wasn't concerned about the presence of an *alien object*. It was more about the reason why it's in your code. The code you presented here, as it is, doesn't replicate the issue. Copy/Paste it in a clean project and see if you get the same results. I don't.